# How to set breakpoint in destructor in Windbg?

Tags: c++, windbg

I have a type `A` which roughly looks like this:

```
class A {
public:
  A() { /*stuff*/ }
  virtual ~A() { /*stuff* }
};
```

What I want to do is set a breakpoint in `A`'s destructor.

What I have tried so far without success:

```
bu myModule!A::~A()
bu myModule!A::~A
bu @@(myModule!A::~A())
bu @@(myModule!A::~A)
```

Those attempts have given me either `Couldn't resolve error at ...` or `Type conflict error at ...`.

What is the correct syntax for setting a breakpoint in the destructor? Is there a way to increase the verbosity of the error messages Windbg is giving in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the correct symbol for your destructor, so using `x` we can determine this:

```
x myModule!A::~*
```

this should output something like:

```
12345678       myModule!A::~A (void)
```

or something similar

then you can set your breakpoint:

```
bp 12345678
```

or

```
bu myModule!A::~A (void)
```

To answer your second question if you start WinDbg with flag `-v` OR press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> then this outputs verbose output see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff561306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)